# Spring Boot 3.2.3 with Eureka 4.1.0 , how to use?

Tags: spring

```
@EnableEurekaServer cannot be resolved to a type on 
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
```

Pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried degrading version of eureka as 4.0.0 , it allows to use the annotation but throws exception as

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration$EurekaServerConfigBeanConfiguration.eurekaServerConfig
```

I am confused , how to create service registry ?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot 3.1.10 and Spring Cloud 2022.0.5 which isn't compatible with Spring Boot 3.2.